# postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: GETSTRUCT

Tags: postgis

when i use pg_upgrade check upgrade postgresql 9.0 beta2 to postgresql 9.3 beta1.
error occure below :

```
uptest@db-172-16-3-33-> cat loadable_libraries.txt 
Could not load library "$libdir/postgis-2.0"
ERROR:  could not load library "/opt/pgsql9.3beta1/lib/postgis-2.0.so": /opt/pgsql9.3beta1/lib/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: GETSTRUCT
```

detailed procedure :

1. install 9.3
2. initdb 9.3
3. install so (pgfincore, pg_stat_statements, postgis, don't install schema sql)
4. check

My `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/pgsql9.3beta1/lib:/opt/postgis-2.0.3-for9.3/lib:/opt/gdal-1.10.0/lib:/opt/geos-3.3.8/lib:/opt/json-c-git20130520/lib:/opt/proj-4.8.0/lib:/lib64:/usr/lib64:/usr/local/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib /opt/pgsql9.3beta1/bin/pg_upgrade -c -b /opt/pgsql9.0beta2/bin -B /opt/pgsql9.3beta1/bin -d /pgdata1099 -D /pgdata2099 -p 1099 -P 2099 -u postgres -v
```

AND then the error :

```
Checking for presence of required libraries                 fatal

Your installation references loadable libraries that are missing from the
new installation.  You can add these libraries to the new installation,
or remove the functions using them from the old installation.  A list of
problem libraries is in the file:
    loadable_libraries.txt

Failure, exiting
```

RESOLVED:

this is a postgis bug for postgresql 9.3.
and resolved it.

thanks.

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/10321

vi /opt/soft_bak/postgis-2.0.3/postgis/geometry_estimate.c

```
//add
#if POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION >= 93
  #include "access/htup_details.h"
#endif
```

and then `gmake`, `gmake install`

do pg_upgrade passed now.

Comment: when the timer lets you, post your edit as an answer. If you comment here I'll upvote it.

Comment: Rather than editing your question and the title, it's best ettiquette to answer your question yourself and select that as the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

This is quoted from question. (OP has edited the question)

#### Quote:

this is a postgis bug for postgresql 9.3. and resolved it.

thanks.

http://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/changeset/10321

vi /opt/soft_bak/postgis-2.0.3/postgis/geometry_estimate.c

```
//add
#if POSTGIS_PGSQL_VERSION >= 93
  #include "access/htup_details.h"
#endif
```

and then `gmake`, `gmake install`

do pg_upgrade passed now.