# PostgreSQL 9.3 - PostGIS 2.0 installation failure

Tags: postgresql, postgis, centos5

My webhosting company has installed postgreSQL 9.3.2 (on a Centos 5.1 VPS that is running Cpanel), but they have given up on trying to install postGIS 2.0.4.

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

works, but none of the functions are actually installed.

How can I install postGIS?

I try importing the postgis--2.0.4.sql file and get this error:

```
 could not load library "/usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/postgis-2.0.so": /usr/pgsql-9.3/lib/postgis-2.0.so: undefined symbol: GETSTRUCT
```

The file postgis-2.0.so is at that location.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644163/solved-postgis-2-0-so-undefined-symbol-getstruct

Comment: It looks like GDAL isn't installing because it needs libmysqlclient15 (I have version 16) and libgeos.so.2 (I have version 3).  I think the GDAL version is:  1.4.2-4.el5.  Would a different GDAL version work?